# Display text if data found or not

Tags: php

The following code will display "email was found" if the email address exists in the database but displays nothing if the data does not exist in the database.

I cannot get it to display "email was not found" if it does not exist.

Can you see what's going wrong?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM membership_main WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            echo "email was not found";
        } else {
            echo "email was found";
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Comment: remove while loop at all

Comment: How many rows you are expecting from a particular email ? I mean multiple email with same email id can be inserted at membership_main table ?

Comment: @splash58 - removing the while loop did it! Something so simple!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code...

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dbconnect.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM membership_main WHERE email = '$email' ";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "email was found";
    } else {
        echo "email was not found";
    }


    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should move following code to out of while

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {
echo "email was not found";
} else {
echo "email was found";
}
}
```

to

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {
echo "email was not found";
} else {
echo "email was found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `while` loop and just check with `mysqli_num_rows()`.

Use while loop after data exist.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$email = $_POST['email'];

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dbconnect.php");

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM membership_main WHERE email = '$email' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "email was not found";
} else {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    echo $row['email']." email was found";
 }
}

mysqli_close($conn);

}

?>
```